# InputManager on OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa

I was wondering if InputManagers are still part of Leopard and if there is a good example that would show me what are the use of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

InputManagers are still available on Leopard, *except*:

- they need to be in the Local domain (`/Library/InputManagers`); you cannot install them per-user any more,
- they need to have appropriate privileges,
- in 64-bit, they won't get loaded at all.

[The Leopard AppKit Release Notes have more specific details.](http://developer.apple.com/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html#NSInputManager)